# How to specify the application which is used to share a post on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When a video is shared on Facebook from Youtube, you can see "Via Youtube" right under the post. How can I specify my application which I use to post on my wall, something like "Via Lomse". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook API does that for you for free, when ever a application post something to a users wall or timeline. The post is identified as posted by your applications name.

Comment: Is there a way to add the application icon or logo to the shared post?

Comment: check the setting of your application settings. See the link: https://www.facebook.com/help/201402119964259/